# Azure Sphere Public API: Delete device group method not working

Tags: rest, azure-sphere

I tried to use Azure Sphere Public API: [Device Group - Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure-sphere/devicegroup/delete) with Node.js.

But I got error message: `Error occurred while deleting deviceGroup --- for tenantId ---`.
(---: my tenant/device group ID)

But the 'Device Group - Get' method worked well. Below is part of the test code.

```
  const config = {
    url: `https://prod.core.sphere.azure.net/v2/tenants/${tenantId}/devicegroups/${groupId}`,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    },
    method: "DELETE"
  };

  try {
    const resp = await axios(config);
    console.log("resp:", resp);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
```

In config, when I change the method to "GET", it works.
But when using the "DELETE" method, an error occurred.

Please check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the problem is role type.

To use `DELETE` method of Azure Sphere Public API, it seems to **need an Administrator role**.

Before I tested with the Contributor role, so got an error.

[image]

with the Admin role, the request is successful.

Comment: It was difficult to determine the cause of the problem because there was only one line of error message when requested. I also can't find this in the official documentation. I hope this improves.